# add callback function to custom function

Tags: jquery, callback, fadein

i have this html code

```
<div class="weather">
<div id="weather"></div>
</div>
```

i'm using this code to hide the weather then display in with fadeIn effect but the fadeIn is not working so how can i make that weather div display with fadeIn effect?

```
    $("#weather").weatherfeed(['SAXX0017']);
    $("select[name='weather']").change(function(){
        var city = $(this).val()
        //alert(city);
        $(".weather").fadeOut(500,function(){
            $(this).children("#weather").empty();
            $("#weather").weatherfeed([city]);
            $(".weather").fadeIn(500);
        });

    });
```

Comment: need to see html after call of .weatherfeed please

Comment: What is `weatherfeed()`?  Surely the fade would have to be after that is completed, and putting it on the next line may not be enough.  If it's an asynchronous call then it will probably take longer than the fade, which is why it appears to not be working.

Comment: it's a function connects to a website to get the weather of the selected code

Comment: Ignore my answer, bad reading. What does `.weatherfeed()` do? Make sure it returns correctly

Comment: Keep in mind, `.weatherfeed()` must immediately repopulate the element with HTML. `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` don't like empty elements, and you have a `.empty()` call just before it.

Comment: .weatherfeed() connects to a website age fetch the weather and it prints the HTML correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments: Connecting to remote hosts is typically done via async calls, which means your `#weather` would be empty when you call `.fadeIn()`, so the animation would not be displayed correctly.

Make sure `.weatherfeed()` is not an async call. If it is, you should attach `.fadeIn()` to its callback instead. If it isn't, try moving the `.empty()` call in it.